# How can I get rid of the weird shadowing/outline on the 3ds max 2013 objects?

Tags: 3dsmax

[image]
I'm new to the program and need this for an assignment so any help on how to get rid of this outline would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a setting in the Viewport options (Views > Viewport configuration). See in the corner, your view mode is set to 'Front - Realistic'? You can change what that entails in the settings, including turning off shadows and the number of lights that shine by default onto scene objects